# How do you write a firefox extension to debug a tab

Tags: debugging, firefox-addon

Just to be clear, I am NOT trying to debug an extension, I want to write an extension that utilises the debugger API to debug a tab in the browser - I need to be able to:

1. programatically set and remove breakpoints
2. receive notifications of breakpoint hits
3. programatically resume the debugger

I did this as a chrome extension and it was pretty easy, as it is well documented. Unfortunately the FF documentation is a nightmare.

I've found a bunch of different pages on how to debug from the scratchpad, but nothing from an extension.

The debugger API docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger-API/Debugger) don't actually say how to get the debugger nor how to attach it to a tab. Though this seems to work for getting a debugger instance, I can't actually use it:

```
let { Cu } = require('chrome');
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/jsdebugger.jsm");
addDebuggerToGlobal(this);
```

I tried this to attach a tab, but it didn't work (`TypeError: argument is not a global object`):

```
dbg = new Debugger;
dbg.addDebuggee(tabs.activeTab.window);
```

Does anyone have any information on how to do this, or a code sample of how to setup the debugger API in an extension to debug a tab in the opening browser?

Comment: any reason you're re-inventing the wheel and not just using firebug?

Comment: @MarcB I need something quite specific, I need to be able to programatically set the breakpoints, i.e. no user interface at all - its for testing something that behaves differently when debugging is present - as I said it was almost trivial to get this working in Chrome, I was hoping FF would be as simple